# общие друзья php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel5

подскажите как вывести общих друзей пользователя user и моих twoUser

всех друзей пользователя вывожу вот так

```
$friendsuser = DB::table('friends')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'friends.friend')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id', 'friends.friend')
            ->select('users.name', 'user_attributes.avatar', 'users.lastonline', 'users.id as id', 'users.slug')
            ->where('friends.status', '>', 1)
            ->where('friends.user', $user->id);

        $friends = DB::table('friends')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'friends.user')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id', 'friends.user')
            ->select('users.name', 'user_attributes.avatar', 'users.lastonline', 'users.id as id', 'users.slug')
            ->where('friends.friend', $user->id)
            ->where('friends.status', '>', 1)
            ->union($friendsuser)
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод intersect:
[Для коллекций](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-intersect) (laravel) 
[Для массивов в php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: а как сделать, сделать такуюже выборку моих друзей, потом выборку друзей пользователя и если так делаю $intersect = $friends->intersect($friendsauths); то ошибка Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

in Collection.php line 677

Comment: Если вы используете Laravel, то можно настроить отношения многое ко многим, создать смежную таблицу в которой будут указаны все взаимоотношения пользователей. и в итоговой выборке можно будет просто выбирать User::find($ids) и у каждого пользователя будет атрибут pivot со списком друзей (их id) и затем уже можно сравнивать через intersect эти списки.

Вот [ссылка](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: а нельзя использовать эти переменные сразу? friends

Comment: Можно к ним применить [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck), и сформировать новые массивы, и уже их сравнить методом intersect